# Compare IP address in textfile. How to search?

Tags: php, search, ip, text-files

I have a textfile there the content is following:

```
TME: 1316179740.2558|FNE: blog-comments.php|MSG: Kommenterade "ett nyare blogginl&auml;gg"-blogginlägget|IPA: ce8bf851d2b1bb1d7f7b24d3656f3d4c90d4ac88c50537e065843b7a0a6c8c236eef76d5814f0782f864209da2b8be1be0d449e86edbcd478847ccbe0189b61f
```

... and so on. IPA stands for IP address and is the visitor IP address. I want to compare this information with the visitors real IP address, so to speak, to get correct information from the file for the visitor. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is that IP address in? It looks like a (very long) hash... 128 characters.

Comment: What kind of hashing did you use to hash the visitor's IP address in the first place?

Comment: @NullUserException: You bet, it ain't!

Comment: I use Whirlpool to hash the IP address

Comment: You are aware that by hashing the IP address you can't get it back, right?

Comment: @Erik Edgren: Makes sense. Now, what is your question, how to extract that IP address from the file, or how to compare the already extracted value against the current visitor's IP?

Comment: @NullUserException: That's the point.

I want to compare the hash-string with the visitors IP addresses hash-string. If match, print out their log to only the visitor who own that IP address

Comment: @Erik Edgren: What is the point, not to be able to get it back, or that you are trying/want to get it back?

Comment: No, I will not get it back. If I want to compare the IP address with another IP address, I only use the hash-string to compare. The IP address are there for in good protection from hackers or whatever

Comment: @Erik Hmmm, why do you bother hashing it at all? Since your application controls access to the file, it's not like visitors could look at someone else's IP address.

Comment: I hash the IP address only to make it safer from other visitors in case of someone fetch the textfile and download it

Comment: Also there are only 2^32 possible IP addresses, so if someone really wanted to, they could reasonably bruteforce all possible IP addresses, and create rainbow table with all possible IP addresses and their respective hashes.

Comment: So you are saying that the unbreakable Whirlpool hash are breakable?

Comment: @Erik No hash is safe from bruteforcing when you have a limited message space. Say I hash a number from 1 to 10. Regardless of the size and complexity of the hash, you could easily hash all 10 numbers and find which one matches. What I am telling you is, 2^32 is a relatively small number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to grab out the important portion and compare that...

```
if (preg_match_all('/IPA:\s*([a-f\d]+)/i', $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    // your values will be in the $matches array here
    // with the actual IP hash in $matches[$i][1]
}
```

I don't know how long the IPA is, or what the ending delimiter is, so this will grab all hexadecimal characters until they run out.

Comment: Thanks, Benjam! But the foreach prints out both lines in the textfiles. I shall only print out 1 line.


    $array = file('textfiles/activity/'.$_GET['d'].'.txt');
    foreach($array AS $key => $test) {
     $info = explode('|', $test);
     $info_date = explode('TME: ', $info[0]);
     $info_msg = explode('MSG: ', $info[2]);
    
    
     if(preg_match_all('/IPA:\s*([a-f\d]+)/i', $info[3], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
      echo '<b>'.date('H:i', $info_date[1]).'</b>: '.$info_msg[1].'<br>';
     }
    }

`$_GET['d']` contains the date for the log.

Comment: What foreach are you referring to?  Do you have some actual code we can look at?  Might make things a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$array = file('textfiles/activity/'.$_GET['d'].'.txt'); 

foreach($array AS $key => $test) { 
    $info       = explode('|', $test); 
    $info_date  = explode('TME: ', $info[0]); 
    $info_msg   = explode('MSG: ', $info[2]); 
    $hashed_ip  = explode('IPA: ', $info[3]);
    if(trim($hashed_ip[1]) == hash('whirlpool', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) { 
        echo '<b>'.date('H:i', $info_date[1]).'</b>: '.$info_msg[1].'<br>';     
    }       
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't print any lines at all. If I only print out $hashed_ip, I get Array

Comment: @Erik Edgren: Updated. Forgot that `$hashed_ip` was part of the array. :)

Comment: Hehe, easy happen :) Na, same result as before - it doesn't print out anything

Comment: @Erik Edgren: Is your IP in the log file? Output `$hashed_ip[1]`, once to make sure it will output the hashed ip.

Comment: Yes, my IP address is in the log file. When I do what you say, I got this:

ce8bf851d2b1bb1d7f7b24d3656f3d4c90d4ac88c50537e065843b7a0a6c8c236eef76d5814f0782f864209da2b8be1be0d449e86edbcd478847ccbe0189b61f

d0d4b981952f59071e5610efcdb239ecdbaecb5c82420523e5ca73ffeb276340eb50c75ad6a5db562d6705de5ead1f0dd4be2a32d192543647579bbe0b2ca408

The first line is my IP address. The second line is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Erik: Are you sure you have that IP, because I tested it with the string you have given and replacing the IP hash with mine. It outputs fine `<b>15:29</b>: Kommenterade "ett nyare blogginl&auml;gg"-blogginlÃ¤gget<br>`.

Comment: Hm. Very strange. Yes, I am very sure about that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3532/discussion-between-erik-edgren-and-shef)